# Wordpress Author Page

Tags: author

Whenever I click on the Author link, I get redirected to the home page.  I've set up the author.php page according to the instruction on codex, but still no luck. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried disabling plugins and switching to default theme?

Comment: No - I can't disable my plugins .. they are vital in the website functioning properly.

Comment: the point of disabling plugins and switching themes is to verify that a plugin or theme isn't interfering with your rewrites and redirecting author pages, which is often an issue. if that's the case you can re-enable them one at a time to find out which plugin is to blame, then we can better help you solve your problem. otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Ok - When I disable the Yoast SEO plugin, clicking on the author link works! Is it possible to tweak the plugin and have the author page work?

Comment: under the plugin's settings `SEO > Indexation`, scroll down to `Archive Settings` and make sure `Disable the author archives` isn't checked.

Comment: @Milo Write an answer please.

Comment: This is the answer:


Under the plugin's settings SEO > Indexation, scroll down to Archive Settings and make sure 'Disable the author archives' isn't checked.

Comment: No, that's a comment, and the question stays _unanswered_. Please write an answer into the answer field (so our search engine can find it) and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the plugin's settings SEO > Indexation, scroll down to Archive Settings and make sure 'Disable the author archives' isn't checked.